# Consolidating Routes in Express.js

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I'm a novice programmer working on a web app. As I have things right now there is a route for every single query to my database. I know there must be a way to use route parameters to direct the route to executing the right function but I am having problems in implementation.

Here is what my routes look like right now:

```
var database = require('./routes/database');

app.get('/query/type', database.type);
app.get('/query/test', database.test);
app.get('/query/another', database.another);
app.get('/query/onemore', database.onemore);
```

Each route is mapped to a function in the database.js file. I would like to try to implement something in the following format which would handle the queries with a single line:

```
app.get('/query/:query', database.query)
```

Where it executes whichever function is named in the parameter :query.

Is there an easy way of implementing this?

Comment: I don't understand why you need this? This is very bad way of exposing your database to the end-user. It has got security concerns. Please check whether you need it that way.

Comment: As I mentioned I'm a novice and really I don't know another way of getting data to the client. I would be grateful if you pointed me in the right direction. I'm using angular on the client and the graph database neo4j for the database itself. The database file holds functions which access the database. The functions initiate cypher queries, some of which are based on user input and others that are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a function that will parse the parameter and use associative array to build the function you want to execute then invoke it. see code below.

```
function parseParam(req, res) {
  var func = database[req.param('query')];
  func(req, res);
}

app.get('/query/:query', parseParam);
```